# How can I store an object which contains a Queue in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

My object, contains a queue which stores DateTime objects. 
Storing objects with just the usual single dimensional properties is not a problem.

What if, I want to store a queue in MySQL using C#. I am using MySQLite and ADO.NET wrapper of System.Data.Sqlite;

Comment: Is MySqlite a database? You metion Mysql but your .NET namespace is System.Data.Sqlite. Did you mean to say Sqlite as in http://www.sqlite.org/?

Comment: Yes and apologies for creating a confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the Object and store it as a binary column, or you can create a new table and store there every item of your queue.

Comment: Hi Muni,
I dont know much about how to create a binary column. Do you mean to say BLOB? Can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes blob is a binary column in sqlite. Check if your ADO.NET class supports it well. As an alternative you can convert the binary data to text (for example in Base64 format, well supported by .net framework class libraries) and store it in a text column.

Comment: Muni,is it possible if I dont want to serialize the entire object but only the Queue?

Or insert the entire queue as a blob?
Your thoughts